# Solving systems of linear equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ali and Zayd have $8.80 in pennies and nickels. The number of pennies is twice the number of nickels. Let p represent the number of pennies and n represent the number of nickels.

Set up the problem as a set of two equations and two unknowns.

eq. 1) 2p+n=?
eq. 2) .01p+.05n=8.80

Comment: Note: The fact that there are two people (rather than one or none) is extraneous information here.

Answer (score 2):

Eq. 1) $$p=2n$$
Eq. 2) $$.01p+.05n=8.80$$